# YUI Dom.getChildren

Tags: javascript, dom, yui

Can you change classes without id when your classes are dynamic and only the parent has an id?

I have something like:

```
<div id="number_block">
  <div class="one science easy left"></div>
  <div class="one science easy center"></div>
  <div class="one science easy right"></div>
</div>
```

I only reach this part

```
var number_block_children = Dom.getChildren('number_block');
for(var i=0; i < number_block_children.length; i++)
{
     /* I don't know the syntax to change class name here for every child, is it possible?
      * I can't use Dom.getElementByClassName...since the class is dynamic.
      * It's something similar to how get classname by id, only I don't have id, just parent id:
      *        Dom.get('id-name-here').className
      * I can't figure out how to do this....
      */

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I'm not sure I understand your problem. Anyway, you have an array of elements. You can use Dom methods like, hasClass, addClass,replaceClass on them.

Comment: I want to replace the classes inside <div id='number_block'>. I can't use hasClass, replaceClass, addClass since the classes are dynamic. So I tried to use getChildren and hopefully get the class attr from each children then replace them. I am syntactically challenged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getAttribute to get element classes:

```
var number_block_children = YAHOO.util.Dom.getChildren('number_block');
for(var i=0; i < number_block_children.length; i++)
{

    var class = YAHOO.util.Dom.getAttribute(number_block_children[i], 'class');
    var classes = class.split(' ');

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know about YUI getAttribute :D Nice!

Answer (score 0):

hey you can do something like

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(window, "load", function() {
    var number_block_children = YAHOO.util.Dom.getChildren('number_block');
    for(var i=0; i < number_block_children.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(YAHOO.util.Dom.hasClass(number_block_children[i], 'one'));
        console.log(YAHOO.util.Dom.hasClass(number_block_children[i], 'two'));
    }
});
```

hope it helps